# SQL Deleting while checking data from another table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have 2 tables, `words` and `lists`.

`words` belong to lists and are references by `listId` field.

`lists` contain a `username` field.

I need to delete a word via it's `id` but first need to check that the username is correct also, therefore I need to reference the lists table.

This is what I have so far but it does not work.

```
DELETE FROM w
USING lists AS l INNER JOIN words AS w
WHERE 
l.username = 'admin'
AND w.listId = 31
AND l.id = w.listId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DELETE w FROM words w
INNER JOIN lists l on l.id = w.listid
WHERE 
l.username = 'admin'
AND w.listId = 31
```

Comment: I changed `AND w.listId` to `AND w.id` and it worked, sorry, i didn't give you enough info

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure about my-sql syntax (I use Oracle), but this should work:

```
DELETE FROM words
WHERE listid in (
  SELECT 31 from lists where username = 'admin'
)
```

...if you really like, you could change the inner select to:

```
SELECT listId from lists where username = 'admin' and listId = 31
```

(but it's not necessary)

Comment: This selects the number 31, I'm not sure it would return something correctly, even on Oracle...

Comment: Right...that is what it is supposed to select!  That is the listId he was trying to delete.